# Trying to implement a points-system in my gamified web app

Tags: flask, web-applications

So I have an exercises page in my flask web app. Each exercise will have a "finish" button. On clicking the finish button, I want to give points to the user currently logged in. The points will then be added to user's progress bar for level-up. I just want a general idea of how to go about it.

This is my user model in database

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    points = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

This is the html file where a button click is going to get points

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" class="w3-large" href="#tip4" onclick="getPoints()">...</a>
```

This is the get points function

```
<script>
function getPoints(){
  points += 20; #How do i access the database.points in this case?
}
</script>
```

```
@bp.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('main.index'))
    form = RegistrationForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User(username=form.username.data, email=form.email.data)
        user.set_password(form.password.data)
        user.points = 0
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Congratulations, you are now a registered user!')
        return redirect(url_for('auth.login'))
    return render_template('auth/register.html', title='Register', form=form)
```

```
@bp.route('/activity1')
@login_required
def activity1():
    return render_template('activity1.html', title='Activity 1')
```

That's mostly what I have for python. Activity1.html is where I want to be able to get points.

Comment: How about calling a function on button press and add points to a counter and have it saved/updated in a database? Do you have any code already to show, any specific difficulties you need help with?

Comment: @gittert I have added some code above. How do I increment the points in database.

Comment: Can you show the python code?

Comment: @gittert I have added some python code above. It mostly consists of the basic flask login/registration setup and the routing. Otherwise, I have not done much there.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this code. It is untested, but I'm sure you get the point (pun intended ;)). Don't forget to change the activity1 template and add points variable there. If you use this code, I would suggest removing the javascript getpoints script there.

```
@bp.route('/activity1', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def activity1():
    user = User.query.filter_by(username = username).first()
    points = user.points

    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = User.query.filter_by(username = username).first()
        points  = user.points + 20
        user.points = points
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Congratulations, you have earned 20 points!')

    return render_template('activity1.html', 
            title = 'Activity 1',
            points = points,
            )
```